# How to prevent most syncing with Google in Android 7.0 Nougat on Samsung devices?

Tags: sync, 7.0-nougat, privacy, background-data, active-sync

In Android 7.0 Nougat on Samsung devices, you can go to **Settings -> Clouds and accounts -> Accounts -> Google** to see a list of all the Google sync options.

Currently,

1. **Sync Calendar** says "Tap to sync now" with "Last synced date" of when I factory wiped the device.
2. **Sync Contacts** is the same as Calendar.
3. **Sync Google Fit data** is the same as Calendar.
4. **Sync Google Play Books** says "Tap to sync now" and "Sync turned off".
5. **Sync Google Play Movies & TV** is the same as Play Books.
6. **Sync Google Play Music** says nothing under it.
7. **Sync People details** says "Tap to sync now" with "Last synced date" of today!
8. **Sync Play Games Cloud Save** is the same as Calendar.

There are **no** enable/disable toggle checkmarks next to any of the items.

In **Settings -> Clouds and accounts -> Backup and restore -> Back up my data** is turned off.

I want all syncing with Google to be turned completely off, and any synced data to be deleted.

The exceptions are for Books, Movies & TV, and Music, for which I would like to manually sync once in a while.

How can this be done?

Comment: Any particular reason why you want this?

Comment: @colbycdev Google hasn't earned my trust, so I want to share as little data as possible with them.

Comment: why not go with no gapps or microg then?

Comment: is your bootloader unlockable?

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to completely remove your Google account from the device and go to your account on Google and delete it

Some Google stuff, even on devices that let you turn off syncing select things in accounts->google->sync, will sync no matter what